# Does Objective-C have something like C++ virtual functions?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, properties, virtual-functions

In objective-c it is possible to add a @dynamic to a property.

Is this also possible for normal instance methods?

**EDIT**
I think i wasn't clear enough.

I want to do the following:

```
@interface MyClass
@property (retain) NSObject *somePropertyObject;
- (void) myMethod;
@end

@implementation MyClass

@dynamic somePropertyObject;

//Make myMethod dynamic. I do not want to implement it. Like C++ Virtual

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be asking how to declare a method that will be implemented some time later somewhere else.

The Objective-C way to do that is to use [**Protocols**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1).

You declare a protocol like this, usually in a header file

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject> {
@optional
    - (void)optionalMethod;
@required
    - (void)requiredMethod;
}
@end
```

This declares two methods, one which is optional and one is required. To use this protocol you declare the conformance when declaring the class that will implement the protocol

```
@interface MyConformingClass : NSObject <MyProtocol> {
}
// you don't have to redeclare methods that are declared in the protocol
@end
```

This new class is checked at compile time for the implementation of `requiredMethod` so it has to implement it, but it can choose whether or not to implement the `optionalMethod`

Now, any class that requires instances of objects to conform to the protocol can declare this, for example, in the interface

```
@interface RequiringClass : NSObject {
    MyConformingClass <MyProtocol> *conformingClassObject;
}
…
@end
```

Again, this is checked at compile time

To make sure that the conforming class implement the `@optional` methods, we can use this handy structure

```
if [conformingClassObject respondsToSelector:@selector(optionalMethod)] {
    [conformingClassObject optionalMethod];
} else {
    // Do something here because the optional method isn't provided
}
```

Examples of this are all over Cocoa - it's a class can provide a list of actions that it would like to farm out to it's delegate, the delegate adopts the protocol and provides the implementations of those delegate methods. The calling object can then check if this delegate responds to those methods at runtime as I've described above, and call those methods to perform actions, or provide information where ever it needs to.

This is used quite a lot in Objective-C, where classes provide a list of methods that they would like some other class to perform, unlike virtual functions, where a class declares functions it wants subclasses to provide implementations for. Particularly as Composition is favoured over inheritance in the language. Rather than create a subclass to provide an implementation, you just create another class that can do the same thing, and add a reference to that in the class instead.

Comment: Protocols are similar to Java/C# Interfaces, and in C++ they'd be closest to an abstract class with no data members, and all pure-virtual methods. I think a protocol would be a bit of overkill for merely declaring a method on a single class for which you intend to provide an implementation at runtime. Personally, I'd save protocols for cases where more than one class will implement (or not) the same methods.

Comment: Think about iOS, where a delegate is used to pass data from a view at the top of the stack to a view controller further down. A common way to do that is with delegation, and that is just a channel between one class and another.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean "How can I declare a method, but not provide a definition which I will subsequently provide at runtime?" Then it's easy, just use a category. Like this:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

// Methods I'll define
- (void)doFoo;

@end

@interface MyObject (DynamicallyProvidedMethods)

// Methods I won't
- (void)myDynamicMethod;

@end


@implementation MyObject 

// Methods I'll define
- (void)doFoo
{
}

@end
```

The compiler will not complain, however if you call -myDynamicMethod at runtime, unless you have provided an implementation for it somehow, it will crash with "unrecognized selector." You can, of course, test for that at runtime by calling respondsToSelector:.

Relatedly, if you're looking to do a near-equivalent of a base class pure virtual method, I would recommend providing an empty implementation that asserts when called if it has not been overridden by a subclass.  You can do that like so:

```
NSAssert((class_getInstanceMethod([self class], _cmd) == class_getInstanceMethod([MyObject class], _cmd)),
    @"Subclass of %@ must override -%@", 
    NSStringFromClass([MyObject class]), 
    NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

// ...where overridesSelector:ofBaseClass: looks like: 
//
//     return ;
```

Of course, that won't alert you to problems at compile time, but it's better than nothing.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

`@dynamic` is just an instruction to the compiler that says: "Don't bother generating accessors for this property, I'm going to provide my own."

Using @dynamic with other methods wouldn't be helpful because the compiler doesn't generate any methods other than accessors for you, and of course you're supplying the other methods anyway.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want an declaration of an method without it's implementation. It's implementation is provided during runtime. Kind like a virtual c++ function.

Comment: @Mats Every Objective-C method is virtual in the sense of C++. Did you mean pure virtual member functions in C++?